# Creating a dictionary from a text file

Tags: c++, vector, struct

This code is supposed to output each word in the file along with the number of times it appears, (EDIT: IGNORING UPPERCASE/LOWERCASE differences). Currently, it is not doing this correctly. Is this due to spaces/punctuation of some kind?

```
struct entry
    {
        string word;
        int count;

    };  


      int main()
        {
            ifstream input1;
            input1.open("Base_text.txt");

            if (input1.fail())
            {
                cout<<"Input file 1 opening failed."<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }

            ifstream input2;
            input2.open("Test_file.txt");

            if (input2.fail())
            {
                cout<<"Input file 2 opening failed."<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }

            vector<entry> base;

            make_dictionary(input1, base);

            int i;
            for (i=0; i<base.size(); i++)
            {
                cout<<base[i].word<<": "<<base[i].count<<endl;
            }


        }

        void make_dictionary(istream& file, vector<entry>& dict)
        {


            string word;

            while (file>>word)
            {
                int i;
                bool found = false;

                for (i=0; i<dict.size(); i++)
                {
                   if (dict[i].word==word)
                   {
                       dict[i].count++;
                       found=true;

                   }
                }


                if(!found)
                {
                    entry ent;
                    ent.word = word;
                    ent.count = 1;
                    dict.push_back(ent);
                }
            }


        }
```

Input

```
This is some simple base text to use for comparison with other files.
You may use your own if you so choose; your program shouldn't actually care.
For getting interesting results, longer passages of text may be useful.
In theory, a full novel might work, although it will likely be somewhat slow.
```

Current (incorrect) output:

```
This: 1
is: 1
some: 1
simple: 1
base: 1
text: 2
to: 1
use: 2
for: 1
comparison: 1
with: 1
other: 1
files.: 1
You: 1
may: 2
your: 2
own: 1
if: 1
you: 1
so: 1
choose;: 1
program: 1
shouldn't: 1
actually: 1
care.: 1
For: 1
getting: 1
interesting: 1
results,: 1
longer: 1
passages: 1
of: 1
be: 2
useful.: 1
In: 1
theory,: 1
a: 1
full: 1
novel: 1
might: 1
work,: 1
although: 1
it: 1
will: 1
likely: 1
somewhat: 1
slow.: 1
```

We are not allowed to use maps on this project. Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I don't see the problem either. "text" shows up twice and is counted twice -- same with several other words.

Comment: Yes, but other words such as "be" are counted twice for no apparent reason. And "For" is not counted twice because one is capitalized.

Comment: @iamthewalrus "may be useful" and "likely be somewhat slow". There are two instances of "be". Is the requirement to count the number of words that are the same regardless of case? Add that to the question, case matters in string comparisons using "==".

Comment: I just ran the file through emacs to make spaces into newlines [I'm sure there are other ways to do that, but I can't be bothered at quarter past one in the morning to figure out how to use `sed` to do it] and then `sort` on the words. And aside from the fact that your input is indeed seeing `.` or `,` on the end of the word as part of the word - and you should probably remove those, and you may want to lowercase the entire word too. It is fundamentally correct, just the details that cause problems - which is a common scenarion. I don't believe there is any builtin way to "skip punctuation"...

Answer (score 0):

If case shouldn't be considered, just convert the word to lower case after reading it.
And then strip trailing punctuation. E.g.

```
while (file>>word)
{
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
    word.erase(word.find_last_of(','), 1);
    word.erase(word.find_last_of(';'), 1);
    word.erase(word.find_last_of('.'), 1);
    ...
```